# Is the authentication system of this website secure enough?

Tags: authentication, php, ajax

Since I write an API for a website, I'm interested in his login system and his requests but something bothered me, I have the impression that the security system is weak...

1. When I login, I send POST request containing the login form, but my **login cookie is plain text** saved ( maybe insecurly deserialized ) -> `a:2:{i:0;s:8:"username";i:1;s:8:"password";}`
2. After successful login, the website starts the session: it defines some variable/functions, it's the first thing it does for any user loading. One of these variables is a **random 40 string characters**, used to validate user requests during the session. This string **changes each time the session is loaded.**
3. This website uses AJAX to format POST request. They are sent unencrypted, it's possible to intercept, edit, then send requests without problems. **Typical POST request looks like:**

```
POST https://www.website.fr/dataprocess/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Host: www.website.fr

logic=[COMMAND]&you=[USERNAME]&key=[SESSION KEY]
```

I edited the request to remove every useless elements, in fact this POST can be accepted by the server if I fill bracket with the right data.

Real request body to illustrate what kind of data I send (copy/pasted from wireshark) :

```
logic=check%3Amail&d%5Bdata%5D=validate&you=apitestaccount&milisec=245&ssrsk=89568&k=788br638757779779168d68a162186678952852z&ismobile=0
```

### I decided to play around by editing request to see what was going to happen:

1 - Legit request with "key" string modified

```
Result: JavaScript pop-up saying I'm connected from somewhere else
```

2 - Legit request with fake username for "you" variable

```
Result: Empty Response
```

3 - Legit request with real username but not mine

```
Result: JavaScript pop-up saying I'm connected from somewhere else BUT IN ANOTHER LANGUAGE
```

**I assume that this user has a different language than mine configured on his account...**

#### According bug logs

The request body is interpreted by PHP (array function) - Unknown version

### Question:

Is there a risk that a maliciously crafted request, in any way, can bypass the key argument and control accounts arbitrarily? Especially knowing that PHP array() (and maybe serialize()) function are used...

Comment: Without even looking hard, saving the username and password client-side on a cookie is enough to say it's not following best practices.

Comment: You claim that the site's AJAX requests are posted without encryption, and you support that claim with an example of a post to an `https` endpoint. That isn't consistent. What am I missing?

Comment: When you write `login cookie`, do you mean POST Data? Or an actual Cookie?

Answer (score 1):

## Deserialization of Untrusted Data

You should **never ever** deserialize untrusted data. This can lead to [PHP Object Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/PHP_Object_Injection). There is also no reason to transmit data as a serialized object, especially if it's only two strings. HTTP already has an easy way to transmit two strings.

## Username in Form

You supply both a user session and a username. This is redundant information and can lead to user impersonation. Generally, the session *should* already be associated to the user it belongs. There should be a table somewhere in an in-memory database like:

| UserId | Session | ExpiresAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71257 | 5ad9aff42efa15cd307f3b467e4a8de4 | 1632926752 |
| 88141 | 15cff5a3776d357ac508e6631f9787a8 | 1632934962 |
| 71004 | 2caee914979fe4e3a8a36c2ae48632f7 | 1632911671 |
| ... | ... | ... |

If the username is stored both with the session *and* given as a request parameter, then one of these is ignored. If it's the one in the request parameter, then you're safe. If it's the one in the session, then you can easily forge requests coming from anyone and impersonate any user, as long as you know their username or user id. Given what you said in your question, I assume the latter is the case.